# Как проверить каких чисел больше в массиве php

Tags: php

Например есть массив, с числами: 1,1,2,1,3,1,2.
Как проверить каких чисел больше в массиве php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php а потом найти большее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть функция [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php).

На вашем примере:

```
<?php
$ar = array(1,1,2,1,3,1,2);
var_dump (array_count_values($ar));
?>
```

Выведет следующее:

```
array(3) {
[1]=>  int(4)
[2]=>  int(2)
[3]=>  int(1)
}
```

Следовательно, единиц в данном массиве больше всего. Дальнейшие действия в зависимости от того, что именно Вам нужно.

Спасибо.